# Sign out of Google sign in on iOS not working in Flutter Firebase flutter fire

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-ios

In my Flutter iOS app, the Firebase sign out of Google is failing.  I use these lines to sign out of Google:

```
  await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

Then I sign in with Apple.  However, when I check the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.providerData`, the google.com provider is still there in addition to the apple.com provider.  Shouldn't this google.com providerData be removed on `GoogleSignIn().signOut()`?

edit: My expectation is that the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.providerData` will be a list of currently signed in authentication providers.  Therefore, I expect that when I sign out of Google, the google.com `providerData` entry would be removed.  Maybe this expectation is wrong, and if so, how do I know what provider(s) the user is currently signed in with?  So, for example, if I want to get the user's name, how do I know which providerData to pull from?

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate more specifically what is not working the way you expect.  If the account that signed in is linked to multiple providers, there can definitely be multiple entries in the provider data, one for each of the linked providers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the question, @DougStevenson.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: how did you implement your providerData? Can you show us the code?

Comment: You have to sign out of firebase too. FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then(....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question stemmed from a misunderstanding of how `providerData` works.  I thought that it would contain the currently signed-in providers.  Instead, it contains all the providers associated with a user in Firebase.

In order to record the username, I recorded the user's name during the sign in process, when the app knows which provider is being signed in.